# How to connect Android GRPC client to azure app service, I am doing such work but its not wroking

Tags: android, mobile, grpc, grpc-java

Basically, this code sign in the user with API, using GRPC but I could not connect the android app.
Every time it returns another error but not the response after searching on too many links it gives another solution which does not work at all

```
        ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(url, port).
        keepAliveWithoutCalls(true).usePlaintext()
        .enableRetry()
        .keepAliveTime(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .keepAliveTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .keepAliveWithoutCalls(true)
        .build();


Account.SignInRequest request = Account.SignInRequest.newBuilder().setEmail("xyz").setPassword("123456").build();
Account.SignInResponse response = null;
public ProtoServiceGrpc.ProtoServiceBlockingStub blockingStub = ProtoServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);


try {
    response = blockingStub.signIn(request);
    Log.i("Response GRPC=>", String.valueOf(response));
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    e.getMessage();
}
```

**And the response from this code is**

```
W/System.err: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: End of stream or IOException
W/System.err:     at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:240)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:221)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:140)
    at com.abc.androidtodoexample.ProtoServiceGrpc$ProtoServiceBlockingStub.signIn(AccountProtoServiceGrpc.java:259)
    at com.abc.androidtodoexample.MainActivity.xoopahGrpc(MainActivity.java:149)
    at com.abc.androidtodoexample.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:30)
    at com.abc.androidtodoexample.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:59)
```

**build file is**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.8'
    id 'idea'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.androidtodoexample"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

def grpcVersion = '1.27.0'

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-auth:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-census:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:${grpcVersion}"
    implementation "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"


    //lastly added
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.39.0'

    implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.5.2'


}
```

Proto File is attached below,

```
syntax = "proto3";


service AccountProtoService{
    rpc SignIn(SignInRequest) returns(SignInResponse);  
}


message SignInRequest{
        string email=1;
    string password=2;
}

message SignInResponse{

    string name=1;
    string username=2;
        string token=3;
    string message=4;
}
```

Is there any problem with the code or Gradle file? Could you help me, please? Thanks

Comment: Please include a copy of the proto file that you're trying to implement.

Comment: @DazWilkin sorry for late, I have edited the question, proto file is included now, Thanks